# Only last page heading added to TOC in phpword

Tags: php, phpword, tableofcontents

I am creating table of content using phpword from heading 1. I have added 2 heading 1 in different page. The heading 1 on last page only added to table of content in output file.
[image: output]

```
<?php
include_once 'vendor/phpoffice/phpword/src/PhpWord/bootstrap.php';
 $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

 $phpWord->getSettings()->setUpdateFields(true);

 $section = $phpWord->addSection();
 $phpWord->addSection(['pageNumberingStart' => 0]);

 $section->addText('Table of Content', 'title');
 $section->addToc();

 $section = $phpWord->addSection();
 $section->addTitle('Título 1', 1);
 $section->addPageBreak();

 $section = $phpWord->addSection();
 $section->addTitle('Titulo 2', 1);
 $section->addPageBreak();

 $phpWord->save('sampleTocOutput.docx');
```